# How to solve 'can only concatenate str (not "ManyRelatedManager") to str' in django

Tags: django, django-models

What needs to be done to solve this error in django , as i am new in django please help me to solve this.

I tried searching on the web for this solution but got nothing.
As much i know the problem is in self.product_name , i want a way to display a manyrealatedmanager.

```
class cart(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.ManyToManyField(Album)
    qty = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(15)])
    price = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.IntegerField(editable=False)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.total_price = self.price * self.qty
    super(cart, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)+' | '+self.product_name+' | '+str(self.qty)+' | '+str(self.price)+' | '+str(self.total_price)
```

I am expecting the data in cart.product_name in form of str.

Comment: `+ self.product_name +` does not make sense, since `product_name` is a `ManyToManyField` to an `Album`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can't i display data in an ManyToManyField

Comment: not without instructing *what* you want to show. Furthermore this will result in an extra query, and especially for functions like `__str__`, I don't know if that is advisable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do u mean by what to show , is it the attribute of Album class u are reffering to?

Comment: ManyToMany = More than One Record Can Be Accessed. You have to either define which one of the manytomany you are accessing. I would personally drop everything in the __str__ to just the self.id ... Don't over complicate the return string...

Comment: If you want to list all products as string you can use `', '.join([str(item.name for item in self.product_name.all())])` if you have `name` field in your  `Album` instance. And you will get all products divided by a coma.

Comment: thanks @SergeyPugach , i hope this will do it.

Comment: @RupeshChaudhari did it helped?

Comment: later i figured it out that i don't need all the products(name) to be displayed , rather i could see them manually by going in into each record.

Comment: @SergeyPugach Thank You